# Convert string into variable within for loop

Tags: ruby

Given the following code in RUBY, I need to loop through a bunch of hashes. The problem is, varX is a string, I need it to be a variable. Any ideas?

```
element1_old = {:ip => "192.168.0.191", :state => "PA", :county => "ambler"}
element1_new = {:ip => "192.168.0.191", :state => "PA", :county => "warrington"}
element2_old = {:ip => "192.168.0.192", :state => "PA", :county => "ambler"}
element2_new = {:ip => "192.168.0.192", :state => "PA", :county => "ambler"}
element3_old = {:ip => "192.168.0.200", :state => "PA", :county => "warrington"}
element3_new = {:ip => "192.168.0.200", :state => "PA", :county => "ambler"}

for i in 1..3
    var1 = "element#{i}_old"
    var2 = "element#{i}_new"
    p element"#{i}".not_in_both("element#{i}_old") 
end
```

Comment: I can't, i'm not the one who created the datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw the hashes into another hash:

```
h = {
    'element1_old' => {:ip => "192.168.0.191", :state => "PA", :county => "ambler"},
    'element1_new' => {:ip => "192.168.0.191", :state => "PA", :county => "warrington"},
    'element2_old' => {:ip => "192.168.0.192", :state => "PA", :county => "ambler"},
    'element2_new' => {:ip => "192.168.0.192", :state => "PA", :county => "ambler"},
    'element3_old' => {:ip => "192.168.0.200", :state => "PA", :county => "warrington"},
    'element3_new' => {:ip => "192.168.0.200", :state => "PA", :county => "ambler"}
}

for i in 1..3
    old = h["element#{i}_old"]
    new = h["element#{i}_new"]
    p new.not_in_both(old)
end
```

I'm assuming that `element"#{i}"` is actually supposed to be `element"#{i}"_new` in your pseudo-Ruby example and that you have monkey patched `not_in_both` into Hash.

Comment: correct, `not_in_both` is a method that i didnt paste into the code above. I'll try your code.